# b64encode when going from Python2 to Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I am running some code that runs on on Python2 to Python3 and it is having some issues. I have a string with formatting:

```
auth_string = '{client_id}:{client_secret}'.format(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
```

and am passing it in as part of "headers":

```
headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b64encode(auth_string)
        }
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

After some research, it is because Python3 considers strings as unicode objects and you need to convert them to bytes first. No problem, I change the line to:

```
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b64encode(auth_string.encode(encoding='utf_8'))
```

But now I get a new error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`b64encode` accepts `bytes` and returns `bytes`. To merge with string, do also `decode`.

```
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b64encode(auth_string.encode()).decode()
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a bunch. Looks like I forgot you need to merge with the string as well.

Answer (score 2):

in Python3, strings are either **bytes** or **unicode**.

Just prefix your strings with **b**:

```
b'Basic ' + b64encode(auth_string.encode(encoding='utf_8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cast your str var to a bytes var:

To cast str to bytes str should be content only ascii chars.

```
base64.64encode(auth_string.encode(encoding='ascii'))
```

or

```
base64.64encode(b'bytes string')
```

Comment: I think you mean to use "encoding=" instead of "encode=" as the latter is an invalid keyword. Your first method at least does not work. Is it possible to prefix a string object? e.g. (b''auth_code)?

Comment: Yes, the param name is "encoding", sorry.

Comment: You cannot use prefix with objects. Should use bytes(mystring.encode(encoding='ascii')) or bytes(mystring.encode('ascii'))